# Access HTTP Post params in Flask while using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, retrofit, jwt, google-signin

I have flask server that works with SQLAlchemy, and JWT tokens.
I'm sending HTTP post request from the client that contains google-id-token.

I'm sending from the this way:

```
@Headers( "Content-Type: application/json" )
    @POST("/auth")
    Call<JsonObject> getGenericJSON(@Body JsonObject obj);
```

On the server: 
First thing - the request gets to the security file:

from models.user import UserModel

```
def authenticate(username, password):
    # user = username_mapping.get(username, None)
    print("DEBUG: username="+username)
    print("DEBUG: password="+password)
    user = UserModel.find_by_username(username)
    if user and user.password == password:
        print ("Returning User") #email, id, last_run, password, routes
        print (user)
        return user

def identity(payload): #unique for jwt. Takes in a payload - the token. We'll exctract the id from the payload, and get the user_id
    print("DEBUG: In identity")
    user_id = payload['identity']
    # return userid_mapping.get(user_id, None)
    return UserModel.find_by_id(user_id)
```

I want to access the google token, but I don't know where is the POST request getting with this JWT authentication.. 
But I can't find it. I know it's supposed to be simple. It is sent for sure becuase the parser requires it. Thanks.

Edit: 
I've tried :

```
        request_data = User.parser.parse_args()
```

But its get to the user get function and not the post function, so it crushes...

Answer (score 1):

Try `token = self.request_args.get('token')`. Replace 'token' with whatever identifier you're sending the token with.